Why does the program call to the function "CheckAnswer" before "DisplayRandomPicture()"?
    public scrLevel1()
    {
        InitializeComponent(GetRightToLeft());
        InitializePictures();
        DisplayRandomPicture();

    }
    

    private void InitializePictures()
    {
        // Initialize pictures with images and answers
        pictures = new List<Picture>
        {
            new(new string[] { @"D:\4Picsdocument\bark1.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\bark2.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\bark3.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\bark4.jpg" }, "BARK"),
            new(new string[] { @"D:\4Picsdocument\computer1.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\computer2.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\computer3.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\computer4.jpg" }, "COMPUTER"),
            new Picture(new string[] { @"D:\4Picsdocument\firm1.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\firm2.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\firm3.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\firm4.jpg" }, "FIRM"),
            new Picture(new string[] { @"D:\4Picsdocument\hero1.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\hero2.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\hero3.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\hero4.jpg" }, "HERO"),
            new Picture(new string[] { @"D:\4Picsdocument\navigate1.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\navigate2.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\navigate3.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\navigate4.jpg" }, "NAVIGATE"),
            new Picture(new string[] { @"D:\4Picsdocument\pollution1.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\pollution2.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\pollution3.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\pollution4.jpg" }, "POLLUTED"),
            new Picture(new string[] { @"D:\4Picsdocument\school1.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\school2.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\school3.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\school4.jpg" }, "SCHOOL"),
            new Picture(new string[] { @"D:\4Picsdocument\triple1.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\triple2.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\triple3.jpg", @"D:\4Picsdocument\triple4.jpg" }, "TRIPLE"),
            // Add more pictures here
        };
    }
    public class Picture
    {
        public string[] ImagePaths { get; }
        public string CorrectAnswer { get; }

        public Picture(string[] imagePaths, string correctAnswer)
        {
            ImagePaths = imagePaths;
            CorrectAnswer = correctAnswer;
        }



    }
    
    private void DisplayRandomPicture()
    {
        position = 0;
        // Randomly select a picture from the list
        Random random = new Random();
        currentPicture = pictures[random.Next(pictures.Count)];
        answer = currentPicture.CorrectAnswer;

        // Display images of the current picture
        pic1.ImageLocation = currentPicture.ImagePaths[0];
        pic2.ImageLocation = currentPicture.ImagePaths[1];
        pic3.ImageLocation = currentPicture.ImagePaths[2];
        pic4.ImageLocation = currentPicture.ImagePaths[3];

        // Define the alphabet
        string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        // Initialize the charArray with enough size
        charArray = new char[20];

        //put the letters of answers involved in the letter button
        for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i = i + 1)
        {
            charArray[i] = answer[i];
        }
        // Randomize more letters for the answer keys
        foreach (char letter in alphabet)
        {
            random = new Random();
            for (int i = answer.Length; i < 12; i++)
            {
                charArray[i] = alphabet[random.Next(alphabet.Length)];
            }

        }
        //Shuffle the letters
        for (int i = 11; i > -1; i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(i + 1);
            var temp = charArray[i];
            charArray[i] = charArray[j];
            charArray[j] = temp;
        }
        // Set the text of the button key to character of charArray
        key1.Text = charArray[0].ToString();
        key2.Text = charArray[1].ToString();
        key3.Text = charArray[2].ToString();
        key4.Text = charArray[3].ToString();
        key5.Text = charArray[4].ToString();
        key6.Text = charArray[5].ToString();
        key7.Text = charArray[6].ToString();
        key8.Text = charArray[7].ToString();
        key9.Text = charArray[8].ToString();
        key10.Text = charArray[9].ToString();
        key11.Text = charArray[10].ToString();
        key12.Text = charArray[11].ToString();
        AnsButton = new Button[answer.Length];
        if (answer.Length == 3)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
            {
                AnsButton[i] = new Button
                {
                    Name = "keyButton{i}",
                    Text = "",
                    Size = new Size(47, 48),
                    Location = new Point(269 + (i * 53), 495),
                    BackColor = Color.Black,
                    Font = new Font("Franklin Gothic Book", 12F, FontStyle.Bold),
                    ForeColor = Color.White
                };
                this.Controls.Add(AnsButton[i]);
              
            }
        }
        else if (answer.Length == 4)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
            {
                AnsButton[i] = new Button
                {
                    Name = "KeyButton{i}",
                    Text = "",
                    Size = new Size(47, 48),
                    Location = new Point(238 + (i * 53), 495),
                    BackColor = Color.Black,
                    Font = new Font("Franklin Gothic Book", 12F, FontStyle.Bold),
                    ForeColor = Color.White
                };
                this.Controls.Add(AnsButton[i]);
                
            }
        }
        else if (answer.Length == 5)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
            {
                AnsButton[i] = new Button
                {
                    Name = $"keyButton{i}",
                    Text = "",
                    Size = new Size(47, 48),
                    Location = new Point(215 + (i * 53), 495),
                    BackColor = Color.Black,
                    Font = new Font("Franklin Gothic Book", 12F, FontStyle.Bold),
                    ForeColor = Color.White
                };
                this.Controls.Add(AnsButton[i]);
                
            }
        }
        else if (answer.Length == 6)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
            {
                AnsButton[i] = new Button
                {
                    Name = $"keyButton{i}",
                    Text = "",
                    Size = new Size(47, 48),
                    Location = new Point(184 + (i * 53), 495),
                    BackColor = Color.Black,
                    Font = new Font("Franklin Gothic Book", 12F, FontStyle.Bold),
                    ForeColor = Color.White
                };
                this.Controls.Add(AnsButton[i]);
               
            }
        }
        else if (answer.Length == 7)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
            {
                AnsButton[i] = new Button
                {
                    Name = $"keyButton{i}",
                    Text = "",
                    Size = new Size(47, 48),
                    Location = new Point(161 + (i * 53), 495),
                    BackColor = Color.Black,
                    Font = new Font("Franklin Gothic Book", 12F, FontStyle.Bold),
                    ForeColor = Color.White
                };
                this.Controls.Add(AnsButton[i]);
                
            }
        }
        else if (answer.Length == 8)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
            {
                AnsButton[i] = new Button
                {
                    Name = "keyButton{i}",
                    Text = "",
                    Size = new Size(47, 48),
                    Location = new Point(138 + (i * 53), 495),
                    BackColor = Color.Black,
                    Font = new Font("Franklin Gothic Book", 12F, FontStyle.Bold),
                    ForeColor = Color.White
                };
                this.Controls.Add(AnsButton[i]);
                
            }
        }
        ansinput = "";
        key1.Click += key_Click;
        key2.Click += key_Click;
        key3.Click += key_Click;
        key4.Click += key_Click;
        key5.Click += key_Click;
        key6.Click += key_Click;
        key7.Click += key_Click;
        key8.Click += key_Click;
        key9.Click += key_Click;
        key10.Click += key_Click;
        key11.Click += key_Click;
        key12.Click += key_Click;

        CheckAnswer();
    }
    private void key_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (position < AnsButton.Length)
        {
            Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
            if (clickedButton != null)
            {
                AnsButton[position].Text = clickedButton.Text;
                ansinput = ansinput + clickedButton.Text;
                clickedButton.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                position++;

            }
        }
    }
    private void CheckAnswer()
    {
        if (ansinput == answer) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
            // Display a new picture
            DisplayRandomPicture();
            // Clear the answer input
            ClearAnswerInput();
        }
        else if (ansinput != answer) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect. Try again.");
            // Reset the position and clear the answer input
            position = 0;
            ClearAnswerInput();
        }
    }

    private void ClearAnswerInput()
    {
        // Clear the text of answer buttons
        foreach (Button button in AnsButton)
        {
            button.Text = "";
        }
        // Reset the position
        position = 0;
    }

I expected it to display random pictures, allow players to click on the keybutton, clicked buttons are showed in the ansbuttons. When all the ansbuttons are filled, use the function "Checkanswers" to check the answer and show the message box. If the answer is correct, display the new one. If not, redo the question. But this code checks the answer before display the question.

I don't even see any Checkanswers-function, nor where you call it.

I call it in here public scrLevel1()
{
InitializeComponent(GetRightToLeft());
InitializePictures();
DisplayRandomPicture();
Checkanswers();
}


do not create multiple random objects. 2) Move the shuffle code to a separate method, and write some unit tests for it. 3) "keyButton{i}" - you probably meant $"keyButton{i}" 4) You should figure out how to calculate the button locations from the answer length, instead of using a bunch of answer.Length == 3 checks


You update ansinput in key_Click, but you only call CheckAnswer that checks that variable in the constructor. You probably want to call CheckAnswer in Key_Click, or have some other event handler call it explicitly.

When I separate the shuffle code, this error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
coming out.

@JonasH My apologies. I skimmed the comments and didn't see an answer, so I looked to find one. I didn't realize you had already basically given the OP the same answer until after I posted mine.

See How to deal with null reference exceptions, especially the part about debugging, since that is an essential skill for any developer.

@OldDog No apology necessary.

You have placed your call to CheckAnswer() at the end of DisplayRandomPicture() before the user has clicked anything. If you place your call to CheckAnswer() at the end of key_click(), it will check the answer after the user clicks a button.
